# R changing factor value

Tags: r

Here is my example:

```
phone_make_factor <- c('apple', 'samsung', 'lg')
phone_make_string <- c('apple','samsung','lg')
df <- data.frame(phone_make_factor, phone_make_string)

df$phone_make_string <-as.character(df$phone_make_string)

df[df$phone_make_string != 'apple' & df$phone_make_string != 'samsung', 'phone_make_string'] <- 'other'

levels(df$phone_make_factor) <- c(levels(df$phone_make_factor), 'other')
df[df$phone_make_factor != 'apple' & df$phone_make_factor != 'samsung', 'phone_make_factor'] <- 'other'
```

Last line of code generates error message:

```
Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, df$phone_make_factor != "apple" & df$phone_make_factor !=  : 
  missing values are not allowed in subscripted assignments of data frames
```

What is the easiest way to change factor value? I am thinking of converting factor to string and then change value and convert to factor afterwards.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `plyr` package's `revalue` method. Here's an example:

```
library(plyr)
revalue(x, c("beta"="two", "gamma"="three"))
```

In your case, you could do something like:

```
revalue(df[df$phone_make_factor != 'apple' & df$phone_make_factor != 'samsung', 'phone_make_factor'], 'other')
```

If that doesn't work, this might be a little more readable:

```
revalue(df$col[!df$col %in% c("apple","samsung","phone_make_factor")],"other")
```

I didn't test this though.

[Source](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Manipulating_data/Renaming_levels_of_a_factor/)